# How can I convert a string to number with freemarker?

Tags: java, jsp, freemarker

I'm a newer develop, I'm working on a project with jsp, freemarker and java-ee. My problem is that I can't convert a string to double with freemarker. I'm using a form to with a double input, if the the input is an integer the validation is done without error, if it's a number with comma, I get an exception said:

FreeMarker template error:
Can't convert this string to number: "43,5"

here is my model :

@Table
public class BalanceConfig extends BaseObject implements Serializable {

```
@Id(sequence = "SEQ_BALANCE_CONFIG")
@SearchCriteria
protected Long id;

@ManyToOne
@SearchCriteria
private Balance balance;

@OneToMany(clazz = BalanceConfigProfile.class, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@SearchCriteria
private List<BalanceConfigProfile> balanceConfigProfiles;

@OneToMany(clazz = BalanceUsage.class, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@SearchCriteria
private List<BalanceUsage> balanceUsages;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Long balanceId;

@Column
@SearchCriteria(type = SearchCriteriaType.LIKE)
private String name;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private String unit;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private String family;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Double conversionRate;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Integer priority;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Date startDate;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Date endDate;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean zeroVisibility;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean portailVisibility;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean crmVisibility;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean selfcareVisibility;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean endDateVisibility;

@Column
@SearchCriteria
private Boolean defaultConfig;

getters and setters;
}
```

the template is :

```
{
    "id"                    : "${balanceConfig.id}",
    "balanceId"             : "${balanceConfig.balanceId}",
    "balanceCode"           : "${balanceConfig.balance.code}",
    "name"                  : "<#if balanceConfig.name??>${balanceConfig.name?json_string}</#if>",
    "unit"                  : "<#if balanceConfig.unit??>${balanceConfig.unit?json_string}</#if>",
    "family"                : "<#if balanceConfig.family??>${balanceConfig.family?json_string}</#if>",
    "conversionRate"        : "<#if balanceConfig.conversionRate??>${balanceConfig.conversionRate?number}</#if>",
    "priority"              : "<#if balanceConfig.priority??>${balanceConfig.priority?number}</#if>",
    "startDate"             : "<#if balanceConfig.startDate??>${balanceConfig.startDate?date}</#if>",
    "endDate"               : "<#if balanceConfig.endDate??>${balanceConfig.endDate?date}</#if>",
    "zeroVisibility"        : "<#if balanceConfig.zeroVisibility??>${balanceConfig.zeroVisibility?string}</#if>",
    "portailVisibility"     : "<#if balanceConfig.portailVisibility??>${balanceConfig.portailVisibility?string}</#if>",
    "crmVisibility"         : "<#if balanceConfig.crmVisibility??>${balanceConfig.crmVisibility?string}</#if>",
    "selfcareVisibility"    : "<#if balanceConfig.selfcareVisibility??>${balanceConfig.selfcareVisibility?string}</#if>",
    "endDateVisibility"     : "<#if balanceConfig.endDateVisibility??>${balanceConfig.endDateVisibility?string}</#if>",
    "defaultConfig"         : "<#if balanceConfig.defaultConfig??>${balanceConfig.defaultConfig?string}</#if>"
}
```

here is the exception:

```
FreeMarker template error:
Can't convert this string to number: "43,5"
The blamed expression:
==> balanceConfig.conversionRate?number  [in template "balanceconfig.ftl" at line 8, column 70]

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> ${balanceConfig.conversionRate?number}  [in template "balanceconfig.ftl" at line 8, column 68]
----------

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----------
freemarker.core.NonNumericalException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.NonNumericalException.newMalformedNumberException(NonNumericalException.java:98)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$numberBI.calculateResult(StringBuiltins.java:223)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$StringBuiltIn._eval(StringBuiltins.java:87)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:115)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:286)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:86)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:243)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:277)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you already have a number in `balanceConfig.conversionRate` (and such). Because `?number` is defined as a string-builtin, its left hand operand is automatically converted to string (similarly as `?upper_case` etc. would do it). Then `?number` tries to parse that string to a number. So this is an unnecessary back-and-forth conversion, which does nothing at best. But, it can also fail. FreeMarker converts to internationalized format (which in the `locale` set there uses comma as the decimal separator), while `?number` is specifically for parsing computer format strings (such as XS types).

So, I think you should write something like this:

```
<#-- These you could do outside the template, in configuration: -->
<#setting number_format="computer">
<#setting date_format="iso">
<#setting datetime_format="iso">
<#setting time_format="iso">
...
"family"                : "${(balanceConfig.family?json_string)!}",
"conversionRate"        : "${balanceConfig.conversionRate!}",
"priority"              : "${balanceConfig.priority!}",
"startDate"             : "${(balanceConfig.startDate?date)!}",
```

Comment: problem solved with some system settings, the number was automatically converted to frensh format with comma. Freemarker's parser doens't recognize a double with comma as a double so I changed the format under Regional and Language >format. and it's work fine thank you.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved with some system settings, the number was automatically converted to frensh format with comma. Freemarker's parser doens't recognize a double with comma as a double so I changed the format under Regional and Language >format. and it's work fine thank you.

Comment: + from me  .. this is  great, i'v been looking for this  for  3 days

Answer (score 0):

conversionRate not looks like a double value.it shows 43,5.It should be 43.5 or 435.So please check what value is coming in the balanceConfig.conversionRate.

Comment: the number is automaticaly transformed to a double with comma even if I enter a double with dot. how can I configure the json response to get double with dot?